# Enable SSH keys on startup in KeePass with KeeAgent plugin

Tags: putty, keepass

I am using [KeePass](http://keepass.info) with the [KeeAgent](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#keeagent) plugin.

I want to log into systems using PuTTY without typing my password (but having an encrypted `id_rsa` file).

I have it configured to the point that if I do this:

1. Start a SSH session using putty and note that I need a password.
2. start keepass
3. Tools -> KeyAgent -> Add -> From File -> `.ssh/id_rsa` -> enter password.
4. Start an SSH session using putty and note that I login without typing password.

But if I stop and start KeePass, the putty session requires a password again.

I would like my `id_rsa` loaded into KeeAgent automatically when keepass starts.

I would expect that when I type my password for KeePass, that it would load the `id_rsa` file without prompting me for an additional password.  I am okay with KeePass storing the `id_rsa` password.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To do so you need a KeePass entry with the private key file attached and allow KeeAgent to use this entry.

- Create a new entry
- Go to the **Advanced** tab and add your private key as an attachment

  [image]
- Go to the **KeeAgent** tab and check "*Allow KeeAgent to use this entry*"

  [image]
- Select the key file from the "*Private Key File Location*" dropdown
- Save and close the entry
- Now open ***Tools*** → ***KeeAgent*** from the menu and select ***Add*** → **From KeePass**

  [image]

This should add the key automatically every time you unlock your database.

Answer (score 1):

I based these enumerated instructions on Martin's response and my experimenting. I would have just edited Martin's response, but he has some extra steps (Specifically, Tools->KeeAgent->Add->From KeyPass) that I did not need.  I suspect I did not need it because I had previously added they key in KeeAgent.

1. Start KeeAgent
2. Edit -> Add Entry
3. Expect "Add Entry" popup window to popup.
4. Click on "Entry" tab.
5. Enter title in "Password" field (I used "SSH Key File").
6. Enter ssh key password in "Password" field.
7. Click on "Advanced" tab.
8. Click "Attach" button on right side of lower half of popup window.
9. Expect file browser window to appear and browse to private key (Mine is .ssh/id_rsa).
10. Click on "KeeAgent" tab.
11. Expect all controls to be disabled (except for "Allow KeeAgent to use this entry".
12. Check box "Allow KeeAgent to use this entry".
13. Expect rest of controls to be enabled and default to file chosen in step 9.
14. Click "OK".
15. Exit KeePass
16. Expect popup asking if you want to save changes.
17. Click "Save Changes"

If Martin merges my answer into his and I will delete this answer and accept his.